# assemble/handlebars: define data context for a template

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

In assemble I want to define *one* data hierarchy and then work on a subset of the data in one template, how can this be achieved?

Example

**stages.yaml**

```
stages:
    stage1:
        goodies:
          - some
          - data
    stage2:
        goodies:
          - more
          - data
```

and then define the data subset like this:

**index.hbs**

```
{{#withStage stage1}}
    {{#each goodies}}
        <p>{{this}}</p>
    {{/each}}
{{/withStage}}
```

I tried registering the following helper:

**helpers.js**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('withStage', function(context, options){
    return options.fn(this.stages[context]);
});
```

but although there was no error, no `<p>` was shown.

For completeness, here are my assemble options:

**Gruntfile.js**

```
    assemble: {
        options: {
            layout: "src/layouts/default.hbs",
            flatten: true,
            data: 'src/data/*.yaml',
            helpers: ['./helpers.js'],
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run into the concept of `partials` which seem to be the way to solve my 'design issue':

added `options.partials` to
**Gruntfile.js**:

```
    assemble: {
        options: {
            ...
            data: 'src/data/*.yaml',
            partials: ['src/partials/*.hbs' ],
            ...
        },
```

and and added **goodies.hbs** into src/partials and put this into
**index.hbs**:

```
{{#each stages.stage1}}
  {{> goodies}}
{{/each}}
```

Still I leave the question open since I want to know what I did wrong with the helper.

Comment: yes, helpers and partials together. however, I think this might be a use case for a plugin as well.